# Troubles with JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have something weird and cannot find out what is causing it.
I have a global array variable defined, `tmpMs`. I fill it using AJAX and `JSON.parse`, that works:

```
function LoadMobs(dung){

    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                // get mobs from PHP
                setTempMobs(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                alert(tmpMs[0].NAME);
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST', 'loadmobs.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("dung=" + dung);

}
```

function setTempMobs goes here:

```
function setTempMobs(mss){    
    tmpMs = mss;
}
```

The alert function within the AJAX works and displays the name of the mob. No surprise.

However if I want to access the "tmpMs" variable right behind the LoadMobs function, it says "Cannot access property 0 of undefined"

```
LoadMobs(currDungBgIndex);
alert(tmpMs[0].NAME);
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Maybe I should mention that all this is happening within some canvas redrawing interval.

Comment: Anything that uses the result of a callback, MUST be inside that callback. Not after it. INSIDE. Also, am I the only one questioning your basic skills when you carefully check for `ActiveXObject` usage, but then blindly use `JSON.parse` without checking if that's supported?

Comment: `LoadMobs` is asynchronous and does not block.  It is called, the AJAX request is kicked off, and then `alert(tmpMs[0].NAME);` is executed long before the AJAX request actually completes.

Comment: @JiriBorek - first half ... well said, unfortunately you then stooped **below** Niet's level